# Issue with handler restarting service

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have an issue where I was handed a gaming service from a dev group in Bulgaria that was coded and built last fall. the only documentation I have for the platform which is a video showing one of the devs running the playbooks to build the env. the video doesnt show version of ansible that is being used. I am trying to run playbooks on ubuntu 16.04 and ansible 2.0.0.2. I am trying to execute the following:

```
- hosts: nler-example-nxx
  user: ubuntu
  tasks:
  - include: ../../templates/nler-nxx.yml
  - name: change nodes ip in nxx config
    replace:
     path: /www/nler-nxx/conf/nxx.properties
     regexp: '(\s+)nxx.defaultPeers=(.*)$'
     replace: '\1nxt.defaultPeers=52.202.223.114; 35.173.242.207; 34.238.136.137; 54.164.46.62; 54.86.17.225;'
    notify:
    - restart nxx service

  handlers:
  - name: restart nxx service
    become: yes
    systemd: name=nxx state=restarted
```

And get this error:

> ERROR! no action detected in task
>
> The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbook/niler/example/nxx.yml': line 15, column 7, but may
>   be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:

```
handlers:
  - name: restart nxx service
    ^ here
```

In doing some research I am thinking this is a version conflict issue but no way to confirm what version they were using.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation is wrong. Should be:

```
tasks:
  - include: ../../templates/nler-nxx.yml
...
```

.

```
handlers:
  - name: restart nxx service
...
```